# How to know how much CPU and RAM I need for new computer?

Tags: memory, cpu, activity-monitor

I got a pimped up macbook pro (i7 3.3GHz i7) from late 2016 atm, but I feel like I could use a less powerful machine.

**I would like to find out what's my current/peak average CPU and RAM usage to see if the new MBA has what I need for what I do.** I'm hopeful there is a better way than to constantly look at activity monitor, and manually logging, to get this kind of info.

*I'm not afraid to go into the terminal*

Answer (score 2):

You could get a 3rd party app like [System Pal](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/systempal/id453164367?mt=12) or [iStat](https://bjango.com/mac/istat/). Both apps reside in the menu bar and tell you things like memory used and CPU usage. You can easily monitor either of these apps. I prefer System Pal to monitor memory and CPU usage. It just gives the top processes.

Another option is to use "top" or "htop" from the command line. These processes are like Activity monitor except it runs via the command line.

Comment: I looked at the websites, but it doesn't tell you if they keep the history. Any chance you know? My idea being that I can leave it on for a week, logs the info and I can see a more realistic usage.

Comment: Good question but I don't know the answer. iStats is very configurable but not very cheap. You may check that out if you haven't. In iStats some things are plotted and it appears the plot will show up to 30 days.